# This project can be run on one computer, but not on another？

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

The error msg(full stack trace):

```
2021-04-24 11:26:28.643 ERROR 26620 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'articleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'articleDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleDao' defined in file [E:\桌面\dcg\target\classes\com\dc\demo\Dao\ArticleDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.dc.demo.DCApplication.main(DCApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'articleDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleDao' defined in file [E:\桌面\dcg\target\classes\com\dc\demo\Dao\ArticleDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleDao' defined in file [E:\桌面\dcg\target\classes\com\dc\demo\Dao\ArticleDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1524) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1404) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:637) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config resource: class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml]; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:590) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:491) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:633) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration.sqlSessionFactory(MybatisAutoConfiguration.java:179) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf6b1f36.CGLIB$sqlSessionFactory$1(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf6b1f36$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$87c7bd6.invoke(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf6b1f36.sqlSessionFactory(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:122) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:99) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:587) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootVFS.preserveSubpackageName(SpringBootVFS.java:61) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootVFS.lambda$list$0(SpringBootVFS.java:53) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootVFS.list(SpringBootVFS.java:54) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.VFS.list(VFS.java:223) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ResolverUtil.find(ResolverUtil.java:250) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.registerAliases(TypeAliasRegistry.java:130) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.registerAliases(TypeAliasRegistry.java:125) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.typeAliasesElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:165) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:110) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Process finished with exit code 1
```

- mybatis-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.dc.demo.Entity"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>
```

- ArticleMapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.dc.demo.Dao.ArticleDao">
 some sql code
</mapper>
```

controller

```
@Controller()
@RequestMapping("/article")
public class ArticleController {
    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @Autowired
    private ArticleClassService articleClassService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ToAddArticle(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("acList",articleClassService.GetAll());
        return "back/article/add";
    }
}
```

service

```
@Service("articleService")
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticleService{

    @Autowired
    private ArticleDao articleDao;

    @Override
    public Integer AddArticle(Article article) {
        return articleDao.AddArticle(article);
    }
    
}
```

There is nothing different between the files. The only difference is the version of the IDE. The old is idea2020, the new is idea 2019. I tried to re-import the project, but still this problem.

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please share the source code that is causing the error for better understanding of the problem?

Comment: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5` Definitely looks like that is the problem. And more importantly, it looks like it is failing inside of `class path resource [config/mybatis-config.xml];` Can you look at this file on your old computer, and compare it to the same file on the new computer? If there are any differences, that might be the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: if you take your target folder to the new system it might work fine.

Comment: @BertAaron Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But there is nothing different.@davidalayachew

Comment: Yes, I think so , I'm trying. Thank you very much.@AliMomeni

Comment: Yes, there is part of the code about Controller,  ServiceImpl and xml.  Thank you. @Krishna

Comment: I add the msg you want to know. Thank you.@ave

Comment: @BertAaron Weird. Try setting a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/aecbff1289c90b1abb12d29e0e3a9fcabe9d97d0/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootVFS.java#L60) and see which file causes the error. FYI, as you use mybatis-spring-boot, you should not use `mybatis-config.xml`. Specify `type-aliases-package` in your `application.properties`. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/#Configuration).